# Moderator history reports an action for the wrong moderator

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, moderation-history

I was watching the history of the actions taken from moderators on *Drupal Answers*, and noticed the following entries.

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47948/customize-the-way-taxonomy-is-displayed

> [image: screenshot]

- [Replacing the (add to compare list link) with the checkbox](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45533/replacing-the-add-to-compare-list-link-with-the-checkbox)

> [image: screenshot]

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45657/create-specific-pages-programatically

> [image: screenshot]

Those questions involve two users that are now moderators: Clive (who who was not moderator when he voted to close the questions), and googletorp. I took those question from the list of actions reported taken from Clive.

> [image: screenshot]

googletorp's moderation history (who effectively closed the question) doesn't have an entry for those questions.

googletorp is surely the user who closed the questions. If Clive voted to close the question as non moderator, and then closed the question as moderator, his name would appear twice, as it happened with https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9713/which-modules-should-i-use

> [image: screenshot]

What should instead happen is showing those questions in the actions taken from googletorp, who really closed the questions.

Comment: I think the post notice counts as the edit. It usually shows up in revisions

Comment: In this case, it shows up in the history of the first moderator, while only the second moderator caused the link to the duplicated question to be added. Even for the second moderator, saying he edited the question is giving wrong information, as the notice about the duplicate is added from the Community user.

Comment: Since you posted a screenshot with mod names anyway (and none of this is really private), your post would be *a lot* easier to follow if you just used names instead of "the first moderator", "the second moderator", "the user who wasn't a moderator at the time", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing as a duplicate automatically adds text to the question with a link to the duplicate. That's why it appears as edited.

An editor (not necessarily moderator) who votes to close a question as a duplicate potentially causes an edit. They don't appear on the edit history.

Each time you vote to close, you choose which question you're voting is a duplicate. This choice gets inserted as an edit, but doesn't count in the edit history. I don't know what happens when you have a tie in the votes, but when there are the right number of close votes, the duplicate is decided by majority. That *can* mean that the last close voter is recorded as editing the question, but other close voters may have done in the interim.

Certainly every time you tip the vote, the possible duplicate text is edited.

Comment: Yes, but it is not done from the moderator for which I am watching the moderation history, nor from the moderator that effectively closed the question.

Comment: No, the edit was caused from the last user who voted to close the question, who is not the moderator for which I am watching the moderation history.

Comment: Are you watching the other close voters? Does it appear that they edited it too?

Comment: The moderation's history shows the activity of who is currently moderator, not other users. What is happening is that the action of closing the question is reported for the wrong moderator. See the question update.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the "Possible Duplicate" message counts as an edit.

Comment: Does it count as edit for every moderator involved in closing the question?

Comment: [Community](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1) *is* a moderator, @kiamlaluno...